# The dimension of $Ax=0$ and $Ax=b$ are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix. Why the dimension of the space of solutions $Ax=0$ and $Ax=b$ are equal?

Comment: Note, that the first "space" is a vector space and the second "space" is an affine space. Those are different mathematical objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that the solutions to $Ax=b$ do NOT form a subspace (so the dimension is defined slightly differently).  The reason is that the solutions space to $Ax=b$ (if it is nonempty) is a shifted version of the solution space to $Ax=0$.

More precisely, if $Av=0$ and $Aw=b$, then $A(v+w)=b$, so $v+w$ is also a solution.  Hence, for any solution to $Ax=b$, we can shift that solution by the solutions to $Ax=0$.  Therefore, the solutions to $Ax=b$ take the solution space of $Ax=0$ and shift the origin to the point $w$ (where $Aw=b$).